# C++ music playback on Mac

Tags: c++, macos

is there an simple and lightweight C++ solution for playing music (aac, or mp3 or m4a) on the MAC OSX platform?

i found the SDL and OpenAL, but they are just to heavy for simple music playback

(the music is intended to be a background music for a game)

thank you

Comment: SDL by itself can play music.  If that's too heavy, then what are you using to write the game right now?

Comment: its written in OpenGL and C++

Comment: How are they "too heavy"? What do you mean by that exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want just music playback and only for osx, I did a little mini-lib that uses the system provided routines to play. Available from here: https://github.com/scoopr/auplay

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep it portable and pure C++ OpenAL is the way to go.

If Mac only is ok then for those file formats it probably is easiest to use CoreAudio. There is an NSSound object which is simpler but it doesn't support those formats. Search for Playing Audio Files in your Xcode documentation to find info about how to play a file using core audio.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, [OpenAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAL) and [FMOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FMOD) are the two major libraries exclusively used to play music (and audio in general).  Stuff like SDL allows for playing audio, but it includes a variety of other things as well, and might be considered 'too heavy'.  Both OpenAL and FMOD have been used in a variety of commercial games, and they're probably you're best option for this sort of thing, outside of writing your own library.